# Creating object in entity after all instance variables were set by Eclipse Link

Tags: object, jpa, entity, eclipselink, instance

The following JPA entity is given:

```
@Entity(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity {

   @Id
   protected String id = null;

   protected String name = null;

   protected String adress = null;

   @Transient
   protected User user = new User(name, adress);

   // Required by JPA
   protected MyEntity() {
   }

   public MyEntity(String id, String name, String adress) {
   // assign instance variables 
   }

   public String getUser() {
      return user.toString();
   }

   ...

}
```

When getUser() will be called on MyEntity created by Eclipse Link the desired String will not be returned. The problem is that User was instantiated before the instance variables of MyEntity were set by Eclipse Link. In other words User was created with name = null and adress = null.

How can I ensure that User will be created after Eclipse Link has set all instance variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`@PostLoad` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)  like this:

```
@PostLoad
private initUser(){
      user = new User(name, adress);
   }
```

The method will be executed once your entity is fully loaded and it's fields are set.

Comment: @user1056903 it is in the JPA standard, so yes it does.

Comment: I have added the annotation to the method. But strangely the method will be executed on entity retrieving only after I restarted the complete application. Does anybody know the reason for that?

Comment: @user1056903 Because the classes used by the application have changed and had to be redeployed to take effect I guess. So does it work now?

Comment: Found the solution why the annotation doesn't work correctly. I've created a Entity Manager for a Persistence Unit only once for the complete application lifecycle. Now an Entity Manager will be created at the beginning of each JPA method and closed at it's end.

Comment: IMO you should give transactions a try - the transaction handling is different, depending on whether you are deploying to a Java EE or SE environment, but transactions are easier and cleaner to work with for transaction demarcation, compared with the EntityManager. Anyway, in case the original issue is solved, you could mark the answer as accepted ;)